# PDO how do I returns the total number of executed queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

With mysql wrapper

```
function query($msql)
{
    $this->last_connection =& $this->connection;
    $this->msql =& $msql;
    $queryult = mysql_query($msql, $this->connection);
    if ($queryult) {
        $this->queries_count++;
        return $queryult;
    } else {
        $this->display_errors();
        return false;
    }
}

function num_queries()
{
    return @$this->queries_count;
}
```

With PDO how to get the total number of executed queries.

Comment: Are you counting the queries performed in a single request/process?  If there are are some options you can build into your object to create this kind of count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are counting your queries in a single process/request and need to know how many execute in the course of performing a single task, you could build this functionality right into your database object using the _construct and _destruct magic functions if you are on php 5.3.  Since your existing function for querying in your object increments this count, you can save it.

Write a _destruct function that will save how many times the query function has iterated down to a log file on the system or to a predetermined place in the database.  This will save the value of the queries_count property out to a place where you can utilize it.

```
function _destruct(){
//write a log file with the value or a serialized version of the database object itself
//set the mode to w+ so it truncates every request
$fh = fopen('/path/to/a/new/log' 'w+');
fwrite($fh, $this->queries_count);
fclose($fh);
}
```

This will run every time your database object is GC'ed.  You can then write a static method in to open the file and read the value.

```
public static function getLastQueriesCount(){
  $fh = fopen('/path/to/a/new/log' 'r+');
  $count = fgets($fh);
  fclose($fh);
  return $count;
}
```

You would of course need write privileges set correctly for this file/directory.  You could substitute the function bodies to store the count however you like - be it flat file format or in a database.

Answer (score 1):

PDO does not count queries. You have to implement it yourself e.g. with a custom extension of the PDO class.